# Discord Components Select Menu. Не работает код, причину найти не могу

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Подскажите пожалуйста. В чем кроется беда? Делал по [гайду](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14XYntpP9W0), но даже так выдает ошибку

Сам код:

```
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.send(content='Select Menu Test', components=[Select(
                                                placeholder='Select Something!',
                                                options=[
                                                    SelectOption(label='Option1', value='1'),
                                                    SelectOption(label='Option2', value='2'),
                                                    SelectOption(label='Option3', value='3'),
                                                    SelectOption(label='Cancel', value='Cancel')

                                                ],
                                                custom_id='SelectTesting'
    )])
    interaction = await bot.wait_for('select Option', check=lambda inter: inter.custom_id == 'SelectTesting' and inter.user == ctx.author)
    res = interaction.values[0]

    if res == 'Cancel':
        await interaction.send('You have canceled your select option')
    elif res == '1':
        await interaction.send('You have chosen option 1')
    else:
        await interaction.send(res)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Katerina\Desktop\proj\bot\botrun.py", line 5, in <module>
    from discord_components import Select, SelectOption
  File "C:\Users\Katerina\Desktop\proj\venv\lib\site-packages\discord_components\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .client import *
  File "C:\Users\Katerina\Desktop\proj\venv\lib\site-packages\discord_components\client.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .interaction import Interaction, InteractionEventType
  File "C:\Users\Katerina\Desktop\proj\venv\lib\site-packages\discord_components\interaction.py", line 28, in <module>
    class InteractionEventType(IntEnum):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\enum.py", line 289, in __new__
    enum_member = __new__(enum_class, *args)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Импорт добавлен.
from discord_components import Select, SelectOption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Select Menu Test',
        components=[
        SelectMenu(
            custom_id='SelectTesting',
            placeholder='Select Something!',
            options=[
                SelectOption(label='Option1', value='1'),
                SelectOption(label='Option2', value='2'),
                SelectOption(label='Option3', value='3'),
                SelectOption(label='Cancel', value='Cancel')

            ]
        )]
    )

@client.event
@on_select_option(interaction):
    if inter.values[0] == "1":
        await interaction.respond(type=6) #обновить селектор, да бы не вылезало: Ошибка взаимодействия.
        await interaction.send('Select Menu Test',
        components=[
        SelectMenu(
            custom_id='SelectTesting',
            placeholder='Select Something!',
            options=[
                SelectOption(label='Option1', value='1'),
                SelectOption(label='Option2', value='2'),
                SelectOption(label='Option3', value='3'),
                SelectOption(label='Cancel', value='Cancel')
                ]
            )]
        )
        await interaction.send('You have chosen option 1', ephemeral=False)
```